# Escape % in field name with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, escaping

I have this SQL-Server query

```
UPDATE qryPETEUR_frmPricingModel() SET [%debtToEBITDA] = '498116.0000' WHERE comp_id = '10004'
```

Which fails because `Update or insert of view or function 'qryPETEUR_frmPricingModel' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.`

I know the issue is because of the % symbol because when I update other fields it works.  Unfortunately I cannot change this field name so I am stuck with it.  I think I need to escape the % symbol and I added a \ in front of it but that didn't work.

What can I do to get this query working?

I am also using Code Igniter if that helps.

EDIT: ConradFrix is on the right track in that %debtToEBITDA is a derived field and I can't change it the way I am trying too.  I took a look at the function `qryPETEUR_frmPricingModel` and discovered I needed to be changing a different field.  So I think this question is done.  Thanks.

Comment: Whoever named that column needs a spanking.

Comment: `when I update other fields it works` are the other fields *also derived*? Something like `debt/EBITDA * 100`

Comment: Can u post the query for the function qryPETEUR_frmPricingModel ?

Comment: I'm not sure that's a valid identifier.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx
"Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed."

Comment: Is this MSSQL because I dont think you are allowed to create columns with symbols like that.

Comment: @JonH [sure you can](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0f95/1)

Comment: @Taz thoes are the *Rules for Regular Identifiers* delimited identifiers e.g. with `[ ]` allow that

Comment: @ConradFrix Ah yes, this is the issue.  It is a derived field and I can't change it the way I am trying.  This is the issue.  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't read the error message. It says nothing about a syntax error. The problem is not a syntax error.

It tells you that you cannot update a computed column. Try to update the source columns which are used to compute the computed column.